# Window load function does not work on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, window, load

When using **Safari (Version 11.1 (13605.1.33.1.4))** every window event functions that I have tried are not working:

**Pure JavaScript:**
`window.addEventListener('load', function() { // code here });`
`window.onload = function() { // code here };`

**jQuery**
`$(window).on('load', function() { // code here });`
`$(window).load(function() { // code here });`

I don't want to use document ready functions, because I have to wait till all images are loaded on the page. If you have something other in mind, please feel free to discuss.

Comment: How about other browsers, is the code working in them?

Comment: Yes, everything is working fine with the other browsers (tested in Chrome and Mozilla).

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue today. I use window on load event to remove class form html when widnow is loaded. The code doesnt work only on Safari browser. 

Did you find the answer @GeorgeStoilov ?

Comment: Experiencing the same issue. I haven't figured out why this isn't working in Safari, but I was able to fix it by using `$('img.some-image').on('load', function() { // code here });` - this worked for me, but it's not the same as waiting until the entire $(window) has loaded. Still, it may point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```js
if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
  callback();
} else {
  window.addEventListener('load', callback);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fake ajax call with empty file and on success do your thing, something like this:

```
function yourFunction(whatShoudIaffect) {

  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../../dummy.php",
    data: '',
    success: function (data) {
      $("#"+whatShoudIaffect).load(window.location + " #"+whatShoudIaffect+" > *");
    }
  });
};
```